# how to use $lookup in MongoDB to replace a field in collection from value in another collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've got a collection called `Home_Katrina1` like:

```
 Type: 'Semi_detached',
 Size: 577,
 Garden: 'Yes'
```

And I've got another collection called `Homes` that contains overall info about a bunch of different homes like:

```
Home_name: 'Katrina_family_home'
Location_code: 35355
```

```
Home_name: 'Katrina_holiday_home'
Location_code: 33556
```

```
Home_name: 'Joel_holiday_home'
Location_code: 34555
```

How can I use aggregation pipelines to add `Location` of `Katrina_family_home` to `Home_Katrina1` given they are matching datasets?

I'm trying to make this output for `Home_Katrina1`:

```
 Area_code: 35355, 
 Type: 'Semi_detached',
 Size: 577,
 Garden: 'Yes'
```

I've tried to use `$lookup` to do this:

```
{
 from: 'Homes',
 let {$Home_Katrina1_HomeName: 'Katrina_family_home'},
 pipeline: [
    { $match: {
      $expr: {$eq: ["$Home_name", "$$Home_Katrina1_HomeName"]}
    },
      {$addFields: {'$Homes.Location'}
    }],
   as: 'Area_code'
```

I know something's wrong with my code - it's not working. Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: What is `Area_code` vs 'Location_code`?   Why is the collection itself named after parts of a field value (`Home_Katrina1` and `Katrina_family_home`)?  Something about your data design seems off.   If you were to simplify and just have the `Homes` collection does that work?    What common info are you trying to extract into a separate collection?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti this is from a set of raw data so the naming conventions are slightly different from each dataset. Supposedly, `Homes` is a summary dataset of all the other home tables

Comment: You cannot do a "dynamic" lookup i.e. given a field value like `Katrina_family_home` process it in some way to arrive at a new string e.g. `Home_Katrina1` and then `$lookup` against that variable.